# Difference Between different Autrelia Import statements

Tags: javascript, import, aurelia

What is the difference between different Aurelia Statement of "Import "

Depending on the case, we find the three syntaxes below:

`import Ajv from "ajv";
import {Ajv} from "ajv";
import * as Ajv from "ajv";`

By searching the internet they seem to be saying that the first syntax imports the namespace and the class but that the other two syntaxes do not. I cannot find any information on what is imported with two other syntax.
What are the elements that are imported with this three syntax? Are there other differences between these three syntaxes?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Aurelia, importing stuff is an ES6/TypeScript thing. There are multiple resources explaining the differences, for example: https://blog.jdriven.com/2017/06/typescript-and-es6-import-syntax/

Comment: Thanks.Its solve my confusion .